# Skip lines when "perl -n"

Tags: linux, perl, unix, command-line

The `-n` argument causes Perl to place a loop around the program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like `sed -n` or `awk`.

Now, is it possible to skip grab some of the forthcoming lines lines in advance in script using `-n`?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wn

if (/my case/) {
  # Skip two lines
  <>; <>;
  # Do something with the line just read.
}
```

The above is not working for me. `$_` is stuck at the same line/content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me:

```
perl -wE 'say for 1..10' | perl -ne 'if (/2/) { <>; <>; print "!$_" } else { print }'
1
!2
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

If you want to process the next two lines, store them in variables.

```
$line1 = <>; $line2 = <>;
```

`<>` on its own doesn't populate `$_` - only in the special case of `while (<>)`.

Comment: *"<> on its own doesn't populate $_ - only in the special case of while (<>)."*, Ahh, that's what got me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use a sliding window buffer.

```
perl -ne'
   push @buf, $_;
   next if @buf <= 3;
   shift(@buf);

   if ($buf[0] =~ /c/) {
      my $line1 = $buf[1];
      my $line2 = $buf[2];
      ...
   }
'
```